Solving a second order differential equation using the method of undetermined coefficients where the right hand side is $6x^2 e^x - 4x^2 +12$
Problem:
Solve the following differential equation:
$$ 2y'' + 3y' - 2y = 6x^2 e^x - 4x^2 +12 $$
Answer:
The general solution is:
$$ y = y_c + y_p $$
where $y_c$ is the complementary solution and $y_p$ is the particular solution. First,
we find $y_c$ by setting up the auxiliary equation.
$$ 2m^2 + 3m - 2 = 0 $$
Now we solve it.
\begin{align*}
m &= \dfrac{ -3 \pm \sqrt{3^2 - 4(2)(-2)} }{2(2)} \\
m &= \dfrac{ -3 \pm \sqrt{9 + 16} }{4} = \dfrac{ -3 \pm \sqrt{25} }{4} \\
m  &= \dfrac{ -3 \pm 5}{4} \\
m  &= -2 \text{ or } m = \dfrac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
$$ y_c = c_1 e^{ -2x } + c_2 e^{ \dfrac{x}{2}} $$
Now we need to find $y_p$.
\begin{align*}
y_p &= Ax^2e^x + Bxe^x + Ce^x + Dx^2 + Ex + F \\
y'_p &= Ax^2e^x + 2Axe^x + Bxe^x + Be^x + Ce^x + 2Dx + E \\
y'_p &= (Ax^2 + 2Ax + Bx + B + C)e^x + 2Dx + E \\
y''_p &= (Ax^2 + 2Ax + Bx + B + C)e^x + (2Ax + 2A + B)e^x + 2D \\
y''_p &= (Ax^2 + 4Ax + Bx + 2A + 2B + C)e^x + 2D \\
\end{align*}
Let $LHS =  2y'' + 3y' - 2y$.
\begin{align*}
LHS &=   2( (Ax^2 + 4Ax + Bx + 2A + 2B + C)e^x + 2D ) \\
 & + 3( (Ax^2 + 2Ax + Bx + B + C)e^x + 2Dx + E ) \\
 & - 2(  Ax^2e^x + Bxe^x + Ce^x + Dx^2 + Ex + F ) \\
%
LHS &=  (2Ax^2 + 8Ax + 2Bx + 4A + 4B + 2C)e^x + 4D \\
& +  (3Ax^2 + 6Ax + 3Bx + 3B + 3C)e^x + 6Dx + 3E \\
& - 2Ax^2e^x  -2Bxe^x - 2Ce^x -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F \\
%
LHS &=  (5Ax^2 + 14Ax + 5Bx + 4A + 7B + 5C)e^x + 4D  + 6Dx + 3E \\
& - 2Ax^2e^x  -2Bxe^x - 2Ce^x -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F \\
%
LHS &=  (3Ax^2 + 14Ax + 3Bx + 4A + 7B + 5C)e^x + 4D  + 6Dx + 3E \\
&  - 2Ce^x -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F \\
%
LHS &=  (3Ax^2 + 14Ax + 3Bx + 4A + 7B + 2C)e^x \\
    &+ 4D  + 6Dx + 3E -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F \\
\end{align*}
Now we have:
\begin{align*}
(3Ax^2 + 14Ax + 3Bx + 4A + 7B + 2C)e^x \\
    &+ 4D  + 6Dx + 3E -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F \\
 &=  6x^2 e^x - 4x^2 +12 \\
%
3A &= -6 \\
A &= -2 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
( 14Ax + 3Bx + 4A + 7B + 2C)e^x + 4D  + 6Dx + 3E -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F &=  -4x^2 +12 \\
14A + 3B &= 0 \\
14(-2) + 3B &= 0 \\
3B &= -28 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
B &= -\dfrac{28}{3} \\
4A + 7B + 2C &= 0 \\
4(-2) + 7\left( -\dfrac{28}{3} \right) + 2C &= 0 \\
-24 - 28(7) + 6C &= 0 \\
3C &= 12 + 14(7) = 110 \\
C &= \dfrac{ 110 }{3}
\end{align*}
The book's answer is:
$$ y = e^{-2x} + e^{ \dfrac{x}{2} } + 2xe^x  - \dfrac{14e^t}{3} + 2x^2 + 6x + 7 $$
Given the book's answer, I am thinking I did find $y_c$ correctly. However, I
am not going to match the book because of the  value of $C$ that I found.
I am wondering where I went wrong. I have two thoughts. The first
is that I started with the wrong form for $y_p$. The second one is that I made a mistake in my algebra. In any case, I am hoping that somebody can tell me where I went  wrong.
Note: My original post did not have the correct answer from the back of the book. The answer from the back of the book is:
$$ y = c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2 e^{ \dfrac{x}{2} } + 2xe^x  - \dfrac{14e^x}{3} + 2x^2 + 6x + 7 $$
Based upon the comment made by Anne Bauval, I updated my work
starting with the equation $3A = 6$.
\begin{align*}
(3Ax^2 + 14Ax + 3Bx + 4A + 7B + 2C)e^x + 4D  + 6Dx + 3E -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F \\
 &=  6x^2 e^x - 4x^2 +12 \\
%
3A &= 6 \\
A &= 2
%
( 14(2)x + 3Bx + 4A + 7B + 2C)e^x + 4D  + 6Dx + 3E -2 Dx^2 - 2Ex - 2F \\
&=  - 4x^2 +12 \\
14(2) + 3B &= 0 \\
3B &= -28 \\
B &= -\dfrac{28}{3}
%
\end{align*}
However, I get  $B = -\dfrac{28}{3}$ which is wrong.

@AnneBauval You are right, there are two constants in the book's answer. The $t$ should be $x$. I made a mistake and I will fix it.

There remains one calculation mistake: just before "Now we have", $LHS=(\dots+3C)e^x+\dots$, not $2C$. Apart from this, your solution is correct and leads to:
$$\begin{cases}3A&=6\\14A+3B&=0\\4A + 7B + 3C&=0\\-2D&=-4\\6D-2E&=0\\4D+3E-2F&=12
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}A&=2\\B&=-\frac{28}3\\C&=\frac{172}9\\D&=2\\E&=6\\F&=7.
\end{cases}$$
The discrepancy with your book comes from a misprint in its question. The ODE corresponding to your book's solution is
$$ 2y'' + 3y' - 2y = 6xe^x - 4x^2 +12 $$
i.e. the first term in the RHS is $6xe^x$, not $6x^2e^x$, which (following your calculation again) leads to $A=0$ and
$$\begin{cases}3B&=6\\7B + 3C&=0\\\dots
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}B&=2\\C&=-\frac{14}3\\\dots\end{cases}$$
Two additional remarks:

As you probably noticed, $y_p=y_1+y_2$ where $y_1,y_2$ can be computed independently as particular solutions of:
$$2y_1'' + 3y_1' - 2y_1 = 6xe^x,\quad2y_2'' + 3y_2' - 2y_2 =- 4x^2 +12.$$
A particular solution of $2y'' + 3y' - 2y=e^xQ(x)$ can be determined more easily by letting
$$y=e^xP,\quad y'=e^x(P+P'),\quad y''=e^x(P+2P'+P''),$$
which results in a simpler ODE:
$$2P''+7P'+3P=Q.$$


I doubled check the book, the term is $6x^2e^x$.

$$
2y^{\prime\prime}+3y^{\prime}-2y=6x^2e^x-4x^2+12
$$
This is my answer.
For $y_c$:
$$
2r^2+3r-2
\\
\implies r_{1,2}=-2,\frac{1}{2}
\\
y_c=C_1e^{-2x}+C_2e^{\frac{1}{2}x}.
$$
For $y_p$, we can use the differental series method (DSM).
We shall use the following formulas:
$$
\frac{1}{D+k}=\frac{1}{k}\quad\left( k\ne 0 \right) 
\\
\frac{1}{f\left( D \right)}e^{\lambda x}v\left( x \right) =e^{\lambda x}\frac{1}{f\left( D+\lambda \right)}v\left( x \right).
$$
$$
\begin{align}y_p&=\frac{6x^2e^x-4x^2+12}{2D^2+3D-2}
\\
&=\frac{6x^2e^x}{2D^2+3D-2}-\frac{4x^2}{2D^2+3D-2}+\frac{12}{2D^2+3D-2.}\end{align}
$$
Set
$$
I:=\frac{6x^2e^x}{2D^2+3D-2}
\\
J:=\frac{4x^2}{2D^2+3D-2}
\\
K:=\frac{12}{2D^2+3D-2}
$$

For $K$:
$$\begin{align}
K&\frac{12}{2D^2+3D-2}
\\
&=\frac{12}{-2}
\\
&=-6.\end{align}
$$
For $J$:
$$\begin{align}
J&=4\cdot \frac{1}{2D^2+3D-2}x^2
\\
&=4\cdot \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{1}{1-\frac{2D^2+3D}{2}}x^2
\\
&=4\cdot \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right) \left( 1+\frac{2D^2+3D}{2}+\frac{9D^2}4\right) x^2
\\
&=-2\left( x^2+\frac32\cdot2x+\frac{13}4\cdot2\right) 
\\
&=-2x^2-6x-13.\end{align}
$$
For $I$:
$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac{6x^2e^x}{2D^2+3D-2}
\\
&=6\frac{1}{2D^2+3D-2}\cdot x^2e^x
\\
&=6e^x\frac{1}{2\left( D+1 \right) ^2+3\left( D+1 \right) -2}\cdot x^2
\\
&=6e^x\frac{1}{2D^2+7D+3}\cdot x^2
\\
&=6e^x\cdot \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\frac{2D^2+7D}{3}+1}\cdot x^2
\\
&=2e^x\left( 1-\frac{2D^2+7D}{3}+\frac{49D^2}9\right) \cdot x^2
\\
&=2e^x\left( x^2-\frac{7D}{3}\cdot2x+\frac{43D^2}9\cdot2\right) 
\\
&=2e^x\left( x^2-\frac{14x}{3} +\frac{86}9\right).\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
y_p=I-J+K=2e^x\left( x^2-\frac{14x}{3} +\frac{86}9\right)+2x^2+6x+7.
$$


(+1) I fixed some calculation mistakes. Now your solution coincides with mine. If you don't agree, feel free to roll back.

hhhhhh,ok!!! @AnneBauval

HINT
I would rearrange the proposed ODE to obtain the following equivalent problem:
\begin{align*}
2y'' + 3y' - 2y = 6x^{2}e^{x} - 4x^{2} + 12 & \Longleftrightarrow (2y'' + 4y') - (y' + 2y) = 6x^{2}e^{x} - 4x^{2} + 12\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2(y' + 2y)' - (y' + 2y) = 6x^{2}e^{x} - 4x^{2} + 12\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2u' - u = 6x^{2}e^{x} - 4x^{2} + 12\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u' - \frac{1}{2}u = 3x^{2}e^{x} - 2x^{2} + 6\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{-x/2}u)' = 3x^{2}e^{x/2} - 2x^{2}e^{-x/2} + 6e^{-x/2}
\end{align*}
Although a little bit tedious, I guess you can handle from here.

I was able to follow your work. I was able to deduce that $u = y' + 2y$. However, I cannot finish it from here. I am hoping that somebody can tell me where I went  wrong in my solution.

@Bob are you acquainted to the integration technics?

I know how to integrate. Would the next line be: $e^{-x/2}u = \int 3x^{2}e^{x/2} - 2x^{2}e^{-x/2} + 6e^{-x/2} ,, dx $ ? If so, I can take it from here.

@Bob Yes, that is it.
